# Double join using twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having trouble using twig. I got three entities, one which is called "article", the standard "User" entity, and another one called "auction".

for every `Auction`, I got 3 attributes: a `price` (integer), a `buyer` (ManyToMany with `User`), and an `article` (ManyToMany with `Article`)

Thing is, when I try to display an auction for a specific user, I try to do so by using

```
{% for auction in auctions if auction.user.id == user.id and auction.article.id == article.id%}
```

But for some reason, I got an error:  Method "id" does not exist

Both of the `Article` and `User` entities got an id, so I think that I cannot access them by using the "something.something.something" method. Is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: is the id public or do you have a getter for id?

Comment: I have a getter for IDs on both entities

Comment: Can you copy paste your entities please?

Comment: You probably forgot about `id` getter, or your `getId()` method is `private`

Comment: Please provide the source of your entities. Otherwise it is impossible to know for sure what's the problem. But if you did set up your relations as ManyToMany, `auction.user` and `auction.article` will be `ArrayCollections`. You would either have to change them to ManyToOne or OneToOne relations, or loop through the users and articles separately.

Comment: It would be wiser to "filter" your `auctions` in your Controller with a call to a `AuctionRepository` function before sending it to the TWIG view. By the way, it will use less memory for your server; imagine what will happen when you'll have a lot of auctions. See this [tutorial (in French)](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/recuperer-ses-entites-avec-doctrine2#subpart_3)

Comment: ok, so I finally fixed this up : pretty easy, indeed. I made a mess with all these entities, but if anyone get stuck on something like that, do it in this way : for every user, you can add x auctions, so all you have to do is a manytomany relation with the auction entity. This entity will have a OneToOne relation with the Article Entity. This way, you can get to your user's auctions with a simple {% for auction in user.auctions if auction.article == article %}. Works just fine.